# Applicative lifting of a function2, function3, ... in scala+cats

Tags: scala, function, scala-cats

I have a Function2 that I'm trying to lift:

```
def myFunction(a: String, b: String): String
```

I'd like to get that function with the signature

```
def myFunction2(a: Option[String], b: Option[String]: Option[String]
```

which should return `None` in case any of the arguments is `None`. In Scalaz, there was `Applicative.lift2` for that case, but I cannot find the same for `cats`.

How can I do the same with `cats`? What about `lift3`, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Apply.ap2`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Apply.html#ap2[A,B,Z](ff:F[(A,B)=%3EZ])(fa:F[A],fb:F[B]):F[Z]). Here's your example implemented using `Apply.ap2`.

```
 import cats.implicits._

 def myFunction(a: String, b: String): String =
   a + b

 def myFunction2(a: Option[String], b: Option[String]): Option[String] =
   Apply[Option].ap2(Some(myFunction _))(a, b)

 assert(myFunction("a", "b") === "ab")
 assert(myFunction2(Some("a"), Some("b")) === Some("ab"))
 assert(myFunction2(Some("a"), None) === None)
```

You also have `ap` functions for more arguments (defined in [`ApplyArityFunctions`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/ApplyArityFunctions.html)), up to `ap22`.