# Java 8 Mapping multiple optional parameters into a function

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Let's say that I have function **`Object f(String a, String b)`** and I want to call two different functions that return Optional Strings to get the parameters for f **`Optional<String> getA()`** and **`Optional<String> getB()`**. I can think of two solutions but neither look all that clean, especially when you have even more parameters:

1:

```
return getA().flatMap(
    a -> getB().map(
        b -> f(a,b)).get()
```

2:

```
Optional<String> a = getA();
Optional<String> b = getB();
if(a.isPresent() && b.isPresent()) {
    return f(a.get(), b.get());
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: definetly prefer the second way, the first one is not understandable and a functional mess

Comment: The fact that you are using `get()` in the first means that you'll get an Exception if either `Optional` is empty, so definitely not the first method.

Comment: Curious to know, what is the else part of (2) which is what could have been an `orElse..` candidate for (1). This is an unclear problem and is driving opinions... and another question that puzzles me at least is, what does the method `f` do such that you need to ensure that both(/all) the values are present before calling it? Just wondering could f accept a varargs such as `Object f(String... args)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just stumbled upon a concept called *lifting* in functional programming, that enables you to *lift* regular functions (e.g. `A -> B`) into new domains (e.g. `Optional<A> -> Optional<B>`).

There's also a syntactic sugar for flatMapping and mapping more comfortably called the *do notation* in Haskell and similar languages, and *for comprehension* in Scala. It gives you a way to keep the flow linear and avoid nesting (that you were forced to go through in your example 1).

Java, unfortunately has nothing of the sort, as its functional programming capabilities are meager, and even `Optional` isn't really a first-class citizen (no standard API actually uses it).
So you're stuck with the approaches you've already discovered.

In case you're curious about the concepts mentioned above, read on.

**Lifting**

Assuming you have:

```
public String f(A a, B b) {
    return b + "-" + a;
}
```

With its Scala equivalent:

```
def f(a: A, b: B) = b + "-" + a
```

Lifting `f` into `Option` (same as `Optional` in Java) would look like this (using Scalaz library, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019867/294657) for Cats)

```
val lifted = Monad[Option].lift2(f)
```

`lifted` is now a function equivalent to:

```
public Optional<String> f(Optional<A> a, Optional<B> b) {
    if(a.isPresent() && b.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.of(b + "-" + a);
    }
    return  Optional.empty;
}
```

Exactly what you're looking for, in 1 line, and works for any context (e.g. `List`, not just `Option`) and any function.

**For comprehension / Do notation**

Using *for comprehension*, your example would look like this (I *think*, my Scala is weak):

```
for { 
    a <- getA();
    b <- getB();
} yield f(a, b)
```

And again, this is applicable to anything that can be flatMapped over, like `List`, `Future` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could stream the arguments and apply the condition only once, but whether or not this is more elegant than your solutions is in the eye of the beholder:

```
if (Stream.of(a, b).allMatch(Optional::isPresent)) {
    return f(a.get(), b.get());
}
```

Comment: You still need the first two lines of #2, so how exactly is this better? It's just longer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that a and b are both present (as your final call to `get` in solution 1 seems to suggest), I think it is pretty straightforward:

```
    return f(getA().orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("a not present")),
             getB().orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("b not present")));
```

If you aren’t sure that both are present, I would prefer your solution 1. It exploits `Optional` the best. Only I would not call `get` at the end, but rather `orElse` or what makes sense in your situation, for example:

```
    return getA()
            .flatMap(a -> getB().map(b -> f(a,b)))
            .orElse("Not both present");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm of the opinion that if there is no good way to use `Optional`, then there is no reason to try to use it anyway.

I find this to be cleaner and simpler than your option 2:

```
String a = getA().orElse(null);
String b = getB().orElse(null);
if(a != null && b != null) {
    return f(a, b);
}
```